# Removing KDE from Fedora21, groupremove not working

Tags: fedora, yum, kde

I am trying to remove KDE from my Fedora 21 installation in favor of XFCE.  I have tried a few different commands and neither of them work.

```
#yum groupremove "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

and also

```
#yum  groupremove  kde-desktop-environment  --exclude=fedora-release\*
```

Both fail to find the kde group and remove it.  I think it has something to do with the fact that I upgraded from fedora20 with fedup and used the non-product selection.

Answer (score 3):

On versions of fedora with DNF, you can remove it much more easily.

```
sudo dnf remove @kde-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove KDE by runnung

`yum groupremove "KDE (K Desktop Environment)"`

or `yum groupremove "KDE desktop"`

or `yum remove kde*`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. I am using `Fedora 22`. When I tried using the command

```
sudo dnf remove kde*
```

it was showing something like `cannot remove the booted kernel` or some error approximately related to this. I tried to login as root and then tried the same command

```
dnf remove kde*
```

It worked fine for me. I also removed the `gnome-classic` package by using the same command. After applying this command, a reboot was required.

Comment: It is probably better to put the asterisk into quotes; e.g., `sudo dnf remove "kde*"`.  If you say `sudo dnf remove kde*` (without quotes) in a directory that contains files with names like `kdefine` and `kdelta`, then `dnf` will see the command line `dnf remove kdefine kdelta`, which may yield unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the KDE desktop, it was `dnf install @kde-desktop`

So when you remove, it is `dnf groupremove kde-desktop`

Comment: Is it really safe? When `dnf` lists the packages about to be removed, it seems that quite a few critical packages for other desktop environments will be removed as well: http://pastebin.com/ptFteqGu

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED 2022 for FEDORA 36: Workstation

I tried to google how to remove KDE Plasma desktop, which was a breeze to install, but failed to find any working answers. I navigated through some of the system etc files and found one that mentioned the group `"KDE Plasma Workspaces"` which was what I used to install it. So I tried the command shown below, and KDE Plasma was removed successfully.

```
sudo dnf groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

You probably already installed KDE plasma, but if for some reason you havn't and your reading this, take my advice when I say that it is not a great desktop for fedora. I remember KDE Plasma being top-notch some years ago, but this recent trial run of the desktop environment that I tried proved to be clunky, slow, buggy, and just an all around terrible experiance. Also people have a hard time removing it once installed. Hopefully this answer will help you with that though.

Answer (score -1):

This command: `yum remove kde*` worked fine for me on Fedora 21.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.